# Hazelcast MapLoader performance - forcing all values to be loaded from database

Tags: cluster-computing, database-performance, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

How do we force all values to be loaded at startup and for this to be done with a single database call? Configuring a maploader with eager loading does not seem to do this? Instead, individual values are loaded, which means a lot of round trips to the database.

The MapLoader implementation snippet looks like this:

```
public V load(K key) {
   // issues a SQL query
   return databaseService.findByPrimaryKey(key);
}
```

Config looks like this:
    mapStoreCfg.setImplementation(loader)
       .setInitialLoadMode(MapStoreConfig.InitialLoadMode.EAGER)

Comment: what version of Hazelcast you are using?
it's designed to work like this: One cluster member loads all keys and then distribute them to cluster members. It batches values loading and I believe batch size is set to 1,000.

Comment: Using 3.8.1. Ok but the performance is very poor against a database. All we actually need to do is a one single SELECT * statement to fetch all rows?

Comment: `SELECT * statement` is not great as it would force Hazelcast to make this choice:
1. load all key-value pairs by a single member and distribute them to other members. this member would become a bottleneck. 
2. all members could get `select * statement`. however this could create an unnecessary load to the DB. as all members would get all keys from the DB.

Comment: If only one member does the SELECT *, then any joining member just receives all the keys from the "primary" (it doesn't need to run its maploader and do SELECT *)?

Comment: Do you find a solution  to do that?@hklf

Comment: We made a hack to preload all values into another map embedded inside the maploader. Then subsequent loadKey calls just loaded from this map thereby avoiding db calls. Once the initial load is done, we wipe the map clean to release the memory. Like I said tho, this is a hack.

Answer (score 0):

MapLoader interface looks as follows

```
public interface MapLoader<K, V> {

    V load(K key);

    Map<K, V> loadAll(Collection<K> keys);

    Iterable<K> loadAllKeys();

}
```

Now,

- The MapLoading orchestrator does `loadAllKeys`
- then it does the `hashing` of keys and distributes all keys in single batches to all partitions according the hashing algorithm, so that each partition gets the keys that the partition is responsible for
- each partition does `loadAll(Collection<K> keys);` where `keys` are the keys that each partition got from the MapLoading orchestrator.

So as a result,

- there is a single loadAllKeys() call
- there are `N` `loadAll(Collection<K> keys)` calls, one executed by each partition, so that the `loadAll(Collection<K> keys)` is called for each batch of keys.